# Liferay EE and SAML Plugin Portlet WAR

Tags: liferay, saml-2.0

I would to follow this  [Tutorial](http://blogs.xtivia.com/home/-/blogs/configuring-liferay-6-1-ee-as-saml-identity-provider-and-service-provider?p_p_auth=RyQYHIH7):
Tutorial SAML

So, I used Liferay EE (30d trial version). 
In the tutorial I must to use SAML Plugin Portlet WAR

In Marketplace" from the menu on the top of this page.
Under the left side menu, there's a search box. I insert "SAML" and I press the "Enter" key 
I can't download this portlet probably because my account is not linked to an Liferay EE (my version is only trial version)
Is correct this way to download the SAML Plugin Portlet WAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EE plugins are only available on the marketplace if you're a registered EE customer. To get hold of EE-only-plugins you'll have to contact Liferay sales.